# Form symfony multiple choice

Tags: forms, loops, symfony, twig

I have a classic form in Symfony and there is one input with 4 different values, I would like to render those 4 values in my twig instead of a drop-down box.

I tried to do it with a loop but I can't do it for an array.

Here is my code :

```
        $isAdmin = !empty($this->getSap()->fetchSapQuery('RECAP_AUTHORITY_ADM', []));

        $flux =  $this->getSap()->fetchSapQuery('RECAP_FLUX_LIST', []);
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('Secteur', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices' => $this->getSap()->fetchSapQuery('RECAP_SECTEUR_LIST', []),
                'label' => $this->trans('Secteur'),
                'choice_label' => 'LibLong',
                'choice_value' => 'SecteurId',
                'required' => true,
                'placeholder' => '',
                'attr' => [
                    //'data-app-auto-select-unique-option' => 1,
                    'multiple' => 'multiple', // secteur monoselection
                ],
            ))
```

Here is my Twig :

```
     {% block body %}
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="card-box ">
            <h2 class="m-t-0 header-title">{{ pageTitle }}</h2>
            <form id="searchForm" class="form-horizontal search-form " role="form" action="{{ 
           path('api_post', {id: odata_search}) }}" method="post">

                {#{{ dump(form.Secteur) }}#}
            {{ form_row(form.Secteur) }}
            {{ form_row(form.Flux) }}
            {{ form_row(form.Canal) }}
            {{ form_row(form.Periode) }}
                {{ form_row(form.CodeExterne) }}
                {{ form_row(form.EQART) }}
            {{ form_row(form.Division) }}
                {{ form_row(form.Username) }}

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-4">
                        <button id="search" type="submit" class="btn btn-success"  data-notification- 
                       clear="true">{{ "Rechercher"|trans }}</button>
                        {% if isAdmin %}
                            <button id="btnNew" type="button" class="btn btn-success" disabled><i 
                          class="fa  fa-plus-circle"></i> {{ "Creer un rapport vierge"|trans }} 
                          </button>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
```

Comment: it's somewhat unclear to me, what you try to achieve. if you want the choice to be rendered as checkboxes/radio buttons, you can just set `'expanded' => true,` as another option to the ChoiceType. If you do that, you should be able to loop over form.Secteur via `{% for childform in form.Secteur %}`, also if multiple selections are possible, you should set `'multiple' => true,` as well (not in `attr` but on the same level as label).

Comment: Hello Jakumi, thanks for your quick answer, I just want to show the 4 different values contained into the input Secteur in my Twig. Actually it is drop-down box where I can see the 4 values and then choose one, I would like to render them in the same time, like if it was an array .

Comment: I want to show the 4 values on the same row like this : Choice 1 / Choice 2 / Choice 3 / Choice 4, instead of a drop-down box where I need to click first and then choose one value.

Comment: have you tried what I suggested?

Comment: Yes, I have my for values rendered as checkboxes/radio buttons when I use 'expanded' => true, I want now hide the radio button and keep only the value and still have the possibility to choose one of the value that will conditioned other results

Comment: Render my values like a menu on a line

Comment: take a look at form themes in symfony